# RFID reader integration with web page

Tags: javascript, activex, html, smartcard, rfid

I have a problem regarding RFID card reader integration to a web page. I found out that the solution is to achieve this ActiveX component and java script.

so, my question is that how can we build a ActiveX component for card reader and the java script Codeline to access this activex Component.

Or if you can suggest an alternate way to integrate RFID reader to communicate directly with a web page, that would be great.

Comment: fyi, meanwhile there was an attempt to specify a [Web NFC standard](https://www.w3.org/community/web-nfc/). Unfortunately the group [announced](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-nfc-20150616/) that the work stopped due to conflicts with the web security model. Strangely they did this only 1 month [after accouncing the first draft](https://www.w3.org/community/web-nfc/2015/05/15/first-draft-of-web-nfc-api-published-by-web-nfc-community-group/). :) Maybe "the community" can continue the work on that draft (while trying to solve the security issues).

Answer (score 2):

SpringCard provides a technical guide and a live demo for developing a web page communicating with a PC/SC reader using Java applet.

You will find it [at the page, under Other resources, Java](http://www.springcard.com/solutions/pcsc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Many USB RFID readers can emulate keyboards, so they can be directly integrated with a web form without needing JS, Java, or ActiveX.

Answer (score 1):

For this task i wrote Windows Service on C#, that listens for web sockets on localhost and listen usb port. Browser connect by WS, and reader handle event on browser through Windows Service

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking Java? It might be possible with it. If you sign you Java applets they will be allowed to access local computer resources.
ActiveX is platform and browser dependent and speaking for myself I will never allow any website to install ActiveX content to my computer.